# How to drag copy a data validation and increment the column letter

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a drop-down list in my spreadsheet, my spreadsheet has a couple of sheets but the main two sheets are "Master" and "Sheet3".

I have made the drop-down list using the **Data** -> **Data validation** as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: Data validation]

And in the "Sheet3" sheet there is a big table (1000 columns) of data that I want to make a drop-down list from, from each column in it.

Now what I want is to drag copy this cell down so that the criteria will be like this:

1. =Sheet3!A1:A
2. =Sheet3!B1:B
3. =Sheet3!C1:C
4. =Sheet3!D1:D
5. ...etc

and so forth for 1000 rows, but when I do this, it does not increment the column letter, it's just like the first cell criteria value (=Sheet3!A1:A) for all other rows.

Is there a way to make this work without me having to edit each row in this 1000-row column manually?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- We have `Sheet3` with 1000 column and we want to get a drop down of all 1000 column in `Master` sheet in a single column.

[image]

### Solution

> **01** - Transpose `Sheet3` to use it as a source of Data validation.

```
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet3!A1:999)
```

[image]

> **02** - Go to Data validation and set the range to `='Sheet3 Transposed'!1:1` as soon as you click save it automatically changes to `='Sheet3 Transposed'!$1:$1` with a abslout refrence just change it back to `='Sheet3 Transposed'!1:1` with removing `$` dollar signs.

[image]

> **03** - Copy the the drop down cell `D2` and paste it in the range `D2:D1001`, we get Error: Invalid Input must fall within specified range, in the whole range `D2:D1001`, to solve it copy the range `'Sheet3 Transposed'!A1:A1000` and in `D2` right click: paste special > Values only

[image]

enjoy :D